# Difficulty with class methods accessing each other in complicated ways

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I am currently creating a game like D&D, using Python. This is the first time I'm using classes outside of Java, and I'm very interested in the way that methods interact.

I got to about here before noticing a problem:

```
import math
import random

class enemy:
    def __init__(self,name='Shrouded Soul',agil=0.0,char=0.0,endur=0.0,stren=0.0,tough=0.0,will=0.0,wis=0.0,luck=0.0,focus=0.0,magpot=0.0,level=None,skills=[],inven={},equipment={}):
        #Name
        self.name = name

        #Attributes
        self.attributes = {
            'agil' : agil,
            'char' : char,
            'endur' : endur,
            'stren' : stren,
            'tough' : tough,
            'will' : will,
            'wis' : wis,
            'luck' : luck,
            'focus' : focus,
            'magpot' : magpot
        }

        #Random attribute gen
        for attrib in self.attributes:
            if type(self.attributes[attrib]) == list:
                self.attributes[attrib] = float(random.randint(self.attributes[attrib][0],self.attributes[attrib][1]))
        if type(level) == int:
            for n in range(level):
                self.attributes[random.choice(list(self.attributes))] += 1.0

        #Stats
        self.stats = {
            'speed' : math.ceil( ( ( (self.attributes['agil'] + ( (self.attributes['agil'] * self.attributes['endur']) ** 0.5)/3 + self.attributes['endur']/2) + 1) * (self.attributes['will'] + 1) ) ** 0.5),

            'health' : math.ceil( ( ( self.attributes['tough']**2 - self.attributes['tough'])/2 + self.attributes['endur']/5 + 1) * (self.attributes['will']/10 + 1) + 24),

            'accuracy' : math.ceil( (40*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['focus']) + 30*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['luck']) + 20*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['will']) + 10) * 10) / 10,

            'stamina' : math.ceil( (self.attributes['endur'] - 1/(self.attributes['will'] + 1) + 1) + (self.attributes['will'] - 1/(self.attributes['endur'] + 1) + 1)/2 + 5),

            'power' : math.ceil( (self.attributes['stren'] + self.attributes['will']/2 + (self.attributes['stren']*self.attributes['will'] + self.attributes['endur']/3)/(self.attributes['stren'] + self.attributes['will'] + 1) + 1 + self.attributes['endur']/5) * 10) / 10,

            'recovery' : math.ceil( (self.attributes['magpot']/5 + self.attributes['endur'] + self.attributes['tough']/3 + 1 + ( (self.attributes['magpot'] * self.attributes['endur'] * self.attributes['tough']) ** 0.5) / 4) / 1.5),

            'awareness' : math.ceil( ( ( ( (self.attributes['luck']/5 + self.attributes['focus'] + self.attributes['will']/3) ** 1.5) + 1.25) / 5) * 10) / 10,

            'sneaking' : math.ceil( ( ( (self.attributes['luck'] + self.attributes['focus']/2 + self.attributes['agil']/3 + 1) ** 0.75) * (self.attributes['focus']/2 + 1) / 4) * 10) / 10,

            'dodging' : math.ceil( (50*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['agil']) + 30*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['will']) + 20*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['luck']) ) * 10) / 10,

            'shielding' : math.ceil( (self.attributes['tough']/2 + self.attributes['will']/3 + self.attributes['stren']) * self.attributes['stren']/4),

            'mPower' : math.ceil( ( ( (self.attributes['magpot'] + self.attributes['stren']/2 + self.attributes['will']/5) * self.attributes['magpot']/4) ** (1/3) ) * 10) / 10,

            'mReserves' : math.ceil(self.attributes['magpot'] + (self.attributes['magpot'] * self.attributes['endur'])**0.5 + (self.attributes['endur']/2)**1.25),

            'mSkill' : math.ceil( (self.attributes['magpot'] + self.attributes['wis']/2 + (self.attributes['magpot']*(self.attributes['wis'] + 1) ) ) ** 0.5),

            'mConcentration' : math.ceil( (50*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['magpot']) + 30*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['focus']) + 10*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['will']) + 10*(1 - 0.9**self.attributes['luck']) ) * 10) / 10
        }
        '''Unused stats'''
        #enemy.capacity = math.ceil( ( (self.attributes['endur']/3 + self.attributes['stren'] + 1) * (self.attributes['will']/4 + 1) ) + 9)
        #enemy.knowledge = math.ceil( ( ( (self.attributes['char']/7 + self.attributes['wis'] + self.attributes['magpot']/11) * (self.attributes['char']/5 + self.attributes['wis'] + 1) + 1) ** 0.75) * 10) / 10
        #enemy.trading = math.ceil( (self.attributes['char']**2 + self.attributes['wis'] + self.attributes['luck']*(self.attributes['luck'] - 1) + 1) ** 0.25)

        #Starting health
        self.hp = self.stats['health']

        #Skillset
        self.skills = skills

        #Inventory
        self.inven = inven

        #Equipment
        self.equipment = equipment

    def showStuff(self):
        print(str(self.name) + '\n')
        print(str(self.attributes) + '\n')
        print(str(self.stats) + '\n')
        print(str(self.skills) + '\n')
        print(str(self.inven) + '\n')
        print(self.equipment)

class weapon:
    def __init__(self,name,kind,dmgRange,minPower=0):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = kind
        self.dmgRange = dmgRange
        self.minPower = minPower

class skill:
    def __init__(self,name,effects,desc=''):
        self.name = name
        self.effects = effects
        self.desc = desc

    def useSkill(self,user,target):
        print(user.name + ' used ' + self.name + ' on ' + target.name)
        if type(self.effects) == list:
            for effect in self.effects:
                if effect.target == enemy():
                    return effect(user=user,target=target)
                else:
                    return effect(user=user)

class effect:
    def dealDmg(user=enemy(),target=enemy(),mod=1):
        if 'weapon' in user.equipment:
            if type(user.equipment['weapon'].dmgRange) == int:
                dmg = max(math.ceil(mod * user.equipment['weapon'].dmgRange - target.stats['shielding']), 0)
            elif type(user.equipment['weapon'].dmgRange) == list:
                dmg = max(math.ceil(mod * random.randint(user.equipment['weapon'].dmgRange[0], user.equipment['weapon'].dmgRange[1]) - target.stats['shielding']), 0)
        else:
            dmg = max(math.ceil(mod - target.stats['shielding']), 0)

        print(target.name + ' received ' + str(dmg) + ' damage')
        target.hp -= dmg

whack = skill('Whack',effect.dealDmg)

branch = weapon('Branch','club',[2,3])

goblin = enemy("Goblin",agil=[1,3],level=5,skills=[whack],equipment={'weapon':branch})

goblin.showStuff()
goblin.skills[0].useSkill(goblin,goblin)
```

### Simple Explanation:

The program declares 3 classes and their individual methods. 1 instance of each class is initialized. A method, `showStuff` (from `goblin`, an instance of class `enemy`) is called, which does not access any other methods. An instance of `skill`, `whack`--stored in a list unique to `goblin`--has one of its methods called, `useSkill`, which accesses a method of class `effect`--which has no instances--`dealDmg`, which gives an output.

At least, that's what it's supposed to do. It sounds more complicated that it looks in the code.

### Problem:

After running the program, I get the following output:

```
Goblin

{'char': 0.0, 'wis': 1.0, 'stren': 1.0, 'tough': 0.0, 'agil': 1.0, 'magpot': 0.0, 'luck': 1.0, 'will': 1.0, 'focus': 0.0, 'endur': 1.0}

{'shielding': 1, 'sneaking': 0.5, 'mConcentration': 2.0, 'dodging': 10.0, 'stamina': 8, 'awareness': 0.4, 'mReserves': 1, 'mSkill': 1, 'health': 26, 'power': 3.2, 'accuracy': 15.0, 'speed': 3, 'mPower': 0.0, 'recovery': 2}

[<__main__.skill object at 0x000001719D7776A0>]

{}
{'weapon': <__main__.weapon object at 0x000001719D7779B0>}
Goblin used Whack on Goblin
```

It *should* be saying `Goblin received 2 damage` or `Goblin received 3 damage`, after `Goblin used Whack on Goblin`.

What causes the above output to not be included? Is it part of the way I call the `dealDmg` method in the `useSkill` method?

If I get this to work it will save so much time/effort than doing it all by hand on paper/calculator.

Comment: Among other things, `type(self.effects) != list`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp You're right - sorry!

Comment: For programs with this kind of complexity, trying to write the code "correctly" can be a hopeless and futile, and you'd want either extensive test coverage or a type system (or a combination) to catch errors like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before going into the crux of your problem, let's address first your `enemy.__init__()` signature:

```
def __init__(self, name='Shrouded Soul', agil=0.0, char=0.0, endur=0.0, stren=0.0,
             tough=0.0, will=0.0, wis=0.0, luck=0.0, focus=0.0, magpot=0.0, level=None,
             skills=[], inven={}, equipment={}):
```

This gets evaluated only once (when Python reads your class) so a new `list` for your default `skills` argument, as well as the two `dict` instances for `inven` and `equipment` will be created only once. Any instance of `enemy` that is instantiated without supplying these parameters will end up sharing them - i.e. if you instantiate two goblins but do not pass new structures for these arguments, they will end up sharing them. If you want each instance to have its own `skills`, `inven` and `stats`, do something like:

```
def __init__(self, name='Shrouded Soul', agil=0.0, char=0.0, endur=0.0, stren=0.0,
             tough=0.0, will=0.0, wis=0.0, luck=0.0, focus=0.0, magpot=0.0, level=None,
             skills=None, inven=None, equipment=None):

             self.skills = skills or []
             self.inven = inven or {}
             self.equipment = equipment or {}
             # etc.
```

Do this for any mutable types (types that can change their internal state while all references to them remain valid) like lists, sets, dictionaries etc. or you might start experiencing weird problems where you don't expect them and it's such an easy thing to overlook. You have a similar thing happening in the signature of your `effect.dealDmg()` method, too.

Now, back to why your problem occurs - when you create your `whack` instance (`whack = skill('Whack',effect.dealDmg)`) you're passing a reference to the `effect.dealDmg()` method which in your `skill.__init__()` method gets stored as `self.effects`. Later on, when you call the `useSkill()` method on it (`goblin.skills[0].useSkill(goblin,goblin)`) you have a check in the same method if `self.effects` is of a type `list`, which it is not (it's an unbounded function) so your `skill.useSkill()` method only gets to print what's going to happen but since you never pass the condition you never get to it happening.

There are also other potential problems (i.e. why would you create a new enemy instance when checking if enemy is set (`if effect.target == enemy():`) when you can just have the default `enemy` to be `None` and then do a simple `if effect.target is None`) but the above is what causes the problem you experience.

Comment: wow, that was completely unexpected. Thanks for all the extra tips too.